# Is photon emission a question of reference frame?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, special-relativity

I have a question about understanding photon emission from a quantum mechanical point of view. I'll give it in terms of experiment to keep things clearer and concrete.

Consider a Van de Graaff generator, we charge it up and disconnect it so we simply have a large object carrying a lot of charge. We then surround the generator with photon detectors:

[image: Stationary Generator]

None of the detectors should register anything as everything is stationary.

Now, we start oscillating our charged generator, for argument let's say a circular motion:

[image: Moving Generator]

The photon detectors should begin detecting; we have a moving charge. Lets say it's fast enough to be producing photons in the low radio spectrum, no problem.

Now, we couple the movement of the photon detectors to the movement of the Van De Graaf generator, lets say by placing everything on a plate and oscillating the whole system:

[image: Coupled Detectors]

The whole system is moving together, therefore the detectors shouldn't detect anything. We know this is true because otherwise we would have had detectors go off due to the acceleration of the planet in the first setup.

Finally, we remove one of the detectors, so we have a hole in our setup. We then place a new detector outside this hole, pointed at the generator:

[image: Stationary Observer]

Our stationary detector should begin detecting from the relative motion of the Van De Graaff generator.

My question is this: Why should the generator be emitting photons in one reference frame but not another? In other words, why does the question *"Is the generator emitting photons?"* have the answer *"It depends on your frame of reference."*

Classically I can make perfect sense of each of the results:

1. The electric charge creates a gradient in the EM field, but everything is stationary relative to each other so you detect nothing.
2. The oscillating charge creates waves in the EM field (photons) that the detectors can now detect.
3. The acceleration of the generator is still producing waves in the EM field from an inertial reference frame, but the movement of the detectors are "in sync" with those waves so nothing is detected.
4. The outside detector is no longer in sync with the waves being produced by the generator, therefore it begins detecting.

However I'm not sure how I should make sense of the results from a quantum mechanical point of view. Is it that the generator is always emitting (*virtual?*) photons, it's just that when everything is oscillating together the backward motion of the detector is enough to rob the photon collision of just enough energy to keep it from kicking off an electron? Would that make it simply a question of relativity, essentially blue shifting the photons into existence?

Does it not make sense to think of the photons being detected as being "emitted" from the generator at all? You could just as easily move only the outside detector and still expect it to detect photons. If you did, how would an inertial observer describe where the photons are coming from?

Comment: Could you explain how that would affect my question? Would the results of the actual experiment differ from my assumptions? I accept that the generator would be able to tell that it's accelerating from its reference frame but I'm not sure that would mean the detectors coupled to it's motion would detect photon emission.

Comment: "The whole system is moving together, therefore the detectors shouldn't detect anything. *We know this is true because* otherwise we would have had detectors go off due to the acceleration of the planet in the first setup." Is that valid evidence? In that situation (generator and detectors both at rest on the earth's surface), would electrodynamics predict enough acceleration-induced radiation of sufficiently-short wavelengths to be noticeable by typical photodetectors?

Comment: > *"The whole system is moving together, therefore the detectors shouldn't detect anything. We know this is true because otherwise we would have had detectors go off due to the acceleration of the planet in the first setup."* As Chiral Anomaly pointed out, this is problematic statement because Earth does not accelerate in the same way an oscillating charged body would. 1) the acceleration of the Earth is due to gravity, which acts on everything, while acceleration of the charged body would be due to mechanical or EM forces in the setup;

Comment: 2) acceleration of the Earth in the frame of the Sun is changing very slowly, it is oscillating with period of 1 year. That is a very low frequency to detect by radiation detector.

Comment: @JánLalinský I see, and what you're saying makes sense. My experiment is definitely flawed. Is this true in the limit case though? If you oscillated a photo-detector at radio-wave frequencies would it detect radio photons from a non-moving static charge? Intuitively it seems like you should. If so, would you still say that the photons detected were "emitted" by the charge? If not, could you explain why or direct me where to look to understand it?

Comment: It depends on what kind of detector it is. Radio receiver would detect radio frequency signal, but not as "photon" but as analog signal.

Comment: @JánLalinský what would be carrying that signal if not photons? Presumably this device: https://www.laserfocusworld.com/detectors-imaging/article/16566810/quantum-circuit-detects-individual-radio-photons would detect a radio photon. Would it make sense to say that the device picked up a photon "emitted" from the charge?

Answer (score 2):

> The whole system is moving together, therefore the detectors shouldn't detect anything. We know this is true because otherwise we would have had detectors go off due to the acceleration of the planet in the first setup.

If you'll indulge me, I'm going to go on for a bit about this.

Since we're referring to bremsstrahlung as our source of radiation, we're encountering the [paradox of radiation of charged particles in a gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field). Fortunately, this is only an *apparent* paradox, meaning it can be resolved.

To summarize the resolution:

Our laws of electrodynamics (including those governing bremsstrahlung) only hold for inertial frames. A charge in free-fall would be in such an inertial frame. On the surface of Earth, however, it is instead supported by a normal force from the ground. As such, the electromagnetic fields in the two frames are not Lorentz invariant. Since a Lorentz transform can not be used, a different transform must be generated. Said transform goes as follows:

$$x'=x$$
$$y'=y$$
$$\frac{g}{c^{2}}(z'-z'_{0})=u(z)\cosh\left(\frac{g}{c}(t-t_{0})\right)-1$$
$$\frac{g}{c}(t'-t'_{0})=u(z)\sinh\left(\frac{g}{c}(t-t_{0})\right)$$

Applied to the electromagnetic fields of the charge in free fall, it is then found to be radiating, and the rate of radiation is the Lorentz invariant:

$$R=\frac{2q^{2}g^{2}}{3c^{3}}$$

Simply put, the acceleration from the Earth only results in radiation when the charge is in free fall.

If you are interested, the original paper can be found [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(60)90105-6), but is unfortunately behind a paywall.

---

Bringing this back to your specific question: the detectors will, in fact, continue to detect radiation when the entire system has been placed on a moving plate as shown in your third image. The emission of radiation is Lorentz invariant.